# animation svg not working on edge/IE

Tags: css, animation, svg, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to create a animation of a svg path and is working well on chrome/firefox but on edge/IE is not.

The code is the follow:

```css
.pathNivel1, .pathNivel2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  -ms-transform: dash 2s forwards infinite;
  animation: dash 2s forwards infinite;
}

@-ms-keyframes dash {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes dash {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

.cls-2, .cls-3, .cls-4, .cls-7, .cls-8 {
    fill: none;
}

.cls-2 {
    stroke: #497faa;
}

.cls-3 {
    stroke: #69c;
}

.cls-2, .cls-3, .cls-4, .cls-8 {
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}

.cls-2, .cls-3, .cls-4 {
    stroke-width: 65px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="275" height="470.85">

        <g>
            
            
            <path class="cls-3 pathNivel2" d="m39.200012,153.566565a82.68,82.68 0 0 1 82.67,82.68" />
        </g>
</svg>
```

What is wrong or missing?

Thx,

Best regards

...........................................................................

Answer (score 1):

I  found a solution on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) on comment of Amelia BR.

```css
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 1000;
  /*stroke-dashoffset: 1000; /* NOT NEEDED */
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 1000; /* zero-length stroke, 
                                 1000-length gap */
  }
  to {
    stroke-dasharray: 1000 0;/* 1000-length stroke, 
                                 zero-length gap */
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" enable-background="new 0 0 340 333" xml:space="preserve">

  <path class="path" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8
 s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41
 C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z"/>
  
</svg>
```